# Free tag - multiple meanings

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The tag [free](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/free) seems to be put on questions with a few different meanings

1. [Software with no cost](https://serverfault.com/questions/15470/free-windows-server-anti-virus-and-firewall-programs)
2. [free memory](https://serverfault.com/questions/110581/memory-reported-by-free-does-not-reconcile-with-physical-memory)
3. [free/busy info in outlook](https://serverfault.com/questions/55728/publishing-free-busy-info-in-exchange-outlook-environment)

It seems either some retagging is in order, or the tag is not too useful and should be banned.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]

Comment: Burninating the countryside. Burninating the peasants. Oh wow...brings me back to college...but without all of the debt

Comment: The best use of the letter S on record, I believe.